# Delete button as a sibling child component in nested array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

Simple delete and update experiment on the list and nested list with React, currently delete doesn't work properly for both the main list and sub list, `console.table()` and it seems to be caused by the `Input` component, ie if I use `<input value={value}>` here the value comes from the parent instead of using local state, delete works. Not sure why? Could it be `Button` component is a sibling to `Input` and something is not set up properly? Quick Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/crud-playgroud-xwrip?file=/src/App3.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App3() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([
    { val: "a", sublist: [1, 2] },
    { val: "b", sublist: [8, 4, 5] }
  ]);
  
  console.table(list);
  const add = (newVal)=>{
    setList([...list, { val: newVal, sublist: [] },])
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Input  placeholder={'add list item'} add={add}/><br/>
      {list.map((e, i) => (
        <ListItem key={i} index={i} item={e} list={list} setList={setList} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

function ListItem({ index, item, list, setList }) {
  const copy = [...list];
  const del = () => {
    copy.splice(index, 1);
    setList(copy);
  };

  const updateSublist = (newSublist) => {
    copy[index].sublist = newSublist;
    setList(copy);
    // console.log(newSublist);
  };

  const add = (newVal)=>{
    copy[index].sublist.push(newVal)
    setList(copy);
  }

  const update = (newVal) => {
    copy[index].val = newVal;
    setList(copy);
  };


  return (
    <>
      <Input value={item.val} update={update} />
      <Button del={del} />
      <div>
        {item.sublist.map((subE, subI) => (
          <SublistItem
            key={subI}
            subIndex={subI}
            subItem={subE}
            subList={item.sublist}
            updateSublist={updateSublist}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <Input placeholder={'add sublist item'} add={add} /><br/>
      <div>--------------</div>
    </>
  );
}

function SublistItem({ subIndex, subItem, subList, updateSublist }) {
  const copy = [...subList];
  const del = () => {
    copy.splice(subIndex, 1);
    updateSublist(copy);
  };
  const update = (newVal) => {
    copy[subIndex] = newVal;
    updateSublist(copy);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Input value={subItem} update={update} />
      <Button del={del} />
    </>
  );
}

function Button({ del }) {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={del}>X</button>
    </>
  );
}

function Input({ placeholder, value, update, add }) {
  
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState(value)
  console.log("value: "+value, "inuptVal: "+inputVal); 
  // console.log(add !== undefined)
  const submit = (e) =>{
    if (e.keyCode === 13){
      if (add !== undefined){
        add(inputVal)
        
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={inputVal}
        //delete work if value={value}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const newVal = e.target.value
          if (add === undefined){
            update(newVal);
          }
          setInputVal(newVal)
        }}
        onKeyDown={(e)=>{submit(e)}}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use `filter`. See [remove the object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66521085/2873538).

Comment: Thanks, mate, I eventually got it to work by removing the hook in the `input` component completely, and only take value from the prop, `<input value={value} onChange={(e)=>update(e.target.value)}>` but I am confused when to use local state,  any reason why we not supposed to use it here? @AjeetShah

Comment: One can keep as many States as one *wants*. But we should think better. We should not create multiple copies (redundancies) of data. Because the biggest pain in that would be - "How to sync all the values?". So, it is better to keep less copies or we should try to create Single Source of Truth. Here is a related concept [Lifting State up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). What is purpose of `Input` component? It is 1. Render input field 2. Send the current value to parent. If you can accomplish this task without State in `Input` component, then, don't have a local state.

Comment: Thanks! I have added another function `add`, and requires a local state to reset input to empty after the enter key, The delete it's still a problem, I guess it might because `delete` is the sibling to `input`, the value passed in from parent and the local inputVal out of sync, still a bit lost on how to fix it, any specific advice? <https://codesandbox.io/s/crud-playgroud-forked-ywjpx?file=/src/App3.js>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone else's benefit, I will answer my own question, the problem lies with KEYs, you need key's when you create the element/subelement, it's risky to assign key during using index `.map((e,i)=><SomeComponent key={i}/>)`because you might end up repeating keys for your elements.

solution:
change `{ val: "a", sublist: [1, 2] },` to

```
    {
      key: uniqueID(),
      val: "a",
      sublist: [
        { key: uniqueID(), subVal: 1 },
        { key: uniqueID(), subVal: 2 }
      ]
    },
```

and `uniqueID()` can be as simple as `Math.random()`
here's the full code for CRUD in a nested list strucutre:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App3() {

  const [list, setList] = useState([
    {
      key: uniqueID(),
      val: "a",
      sublist: [
        { key: uniqueID(), subVal: 1 },
        { key: uniqueID(), subVal: 2 }
      ]
    },
    {
      key: uniqueID(),
      val: "b",
      sublist: [
        { key: uniqueID(), subVal: 8 },
        { key: uniqueID(), subVal: 4 },
        { key: uniqueID(), subVal: 3 }
      ]
    }
  ]);

  console.table(list);
  const add = (newVal) => {
    setList([...list, { key: uniqueID(), val: newVal, sublist: [] }]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Input placeholder={"add list item"} add={add} />
      <br />
      {list.map((e, i) => (
        <ListItem
          key={e.key}
          index={i}
          item={e}
          list={list}
          setList={setList}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

function ListItem({ index, item, list, setList }) {
  const copy = [...list];
  const del = () => {
    copy.splice(index, 1);
    setList(copy);
  };

  const updateSublist = (newSublist) => {
    copy[index].sublist = newSublist;
    setList(copy);
    // console.log(newSublist);
  };

  const add = (newVal) => {
    copy[index].sublist.push({ key: uniqueID(), subVal: newVal });
    setList(copy);
  };

  const update = (newVal) => {
    copy[index].val = newVal;
    setList(copy);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Input value={item.val} update={update} />
      <Button del={del} />
      <div>
        {item.sublist.map((subE, subI) => (
          <SublistItem
            key={subE.key}
            subIndex={subI}
            subItem={subE}
            subList={item.sublist}
            updateSublist={updateSublist}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <Input placeholder={"add sublist item"} add={add} />
      <br />
      <div>--------------</div>
    </>
  );
}

function SublistItem({ subIndex, subItem, subList, updateSublist }) {
  const copy = [...subList];

  const del = () => {
    copy.splice(subIndex, 1);
    updateSublist(copy);
  };
  const update = (newVal) => {
    copy[subIndex].subVal = newVal;
    updateSublist(copy);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Input value={subItem.subVal} update={update} />
      <Button del={del} />
    </>
  );
}

function Button({ del }) {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={del}>X</button>
    </>
  );
}

function Input({ placeholder, value, update, add }) {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState(value);
  console.log("value: " + value, "inuptVal: " + inputVal);
  // console.log(add !== undefined)
  const submit = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      if (add !== undefined) {
        add(inputVal);
        setInputVal("");
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        // key={value}
        value={inputVal}
        //delete work if value={value}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const newVal = e.target.value;
          if (add === undefined) {
            update(newVal);
          }
          setInputVal(newVal);
        }}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          submit(e);
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}


const uniqueID = () => {
  return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000000000000) | 0)
    .toString(32)
    .substr(1);
};
```